# webpack (install --save-dev) vs. (install --save)

Tags: webpack, babeljs

Is webpack always installed under devDependencies ?

I am a little confused if we need to install webpack under (production) dependencies when we want to set `mode = 'production'`.

Also, is babel always under devDependencies too ?

Comment: Yes. You need webpack and babel to develop (pack and transpile) your application. You do not need to ship them with the packed app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dev Dependencies are what you need to develop your app. Webpack packs it, Babel transpiles it. You can also add eslint to the list if you want. Those will not be shipped with the final packed app.

Dependencies are your app dependencies, what it needs in order to *work*. Those will mainly be the modules you require in your sources.

Testing tools (Karma, Mocha, Jest, etc...) are also Dev Dependencies.

Comment: But webpack creates 'in-memory' bundle with devServer. How do you ship that in-memory bundle ? Don't you need to install webpack in (produciton) dependencies for that ?

Comment: @KayaToast devServer is, as the name suggests, for development only. For production you build static files and serve them "normally" on the production server.